# How to query only specific columns?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Typical scenario:

```
SomeModule.find(:all, :conditions ["xyz" = ?, some_var]
SomeModule.find(:first, :conditions ["xyz" = ?, some_var]
SomeModule.find(:last, :conditions ["xyz" = ?, some_var]
```

Desired Equivilent:

While the above three examples are great, I'm looking for the correct way to to ask for 'only' specific columns, such as:

```
SomeModule.find(:first_name, last_name, city :conditions ["xyz" = ?, some_var]
```

-- Or perhaps --

```
SomeModule.find(:only => :first_name, :last_name, :city :conditions ["xyz" = ?, some_var]
```

What is the rails way of eliminating unnecessary columns in the query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SomeModule.find(:select => "first_name, last_name, city" ... )
```

Documentation: [ActiveRecord::QueryMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-select)

Comment: Exactly what the doctor ordered. You guys never cease to amaze me. Works perfect!! And the speed at which you respond is nothing short of magic.

Comment: To be honest, my reply was edited and improved by other 3 members shortly after I post it - really nice. Thanks and glad to help.